# Chrome extension messaging: sendResponse returning empty object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a Chrome extension and I want to get the currently selected text after the user click on a context menu. I'm trying to do it by sending a message from the background script to the content script but the object returned from the content script is always empty.

Here's the relevant code:

background_script.js:

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "getSelection"}, undefined, function(response){
            console.log(response.data); // <--- this is undefined
        });
    });
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);
```

content_script.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( 
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.method == "getSelection"){
            var selection = window.getSelection(); // <--- this is ok
            sendResponse({data: selection}); 
            return true;
        }
    }
)
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Browser Extension",
    "description": "Browser Extension",
    "version": "0.1",

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background_script.js"
        ]
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ],

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

The main issue in similar cases seems to be a missing `return true;` statement but I've added that. Also, the `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` function has a new parameter `options` but it makes no difference whether I omit it or pass an undefined or empty value.

Thank you :)

EDIT:`chrome.runtime.lastError` in the sendMessage function is undefined so no apparent errors!

Comment: Don't use undefined as the 3rd argument of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. Simply eliminate that argument, i.e: `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response){`

Comment: Thanks @iván, that's how I did it in the first place but unfortunately it isn't working anyway :(

Comment: `Selection` is a complex DOM class, it's not JSON'ifiable, so you need to add `.toString()`

Comment: This was it, thank you @wOxxOm! I had also tried with just a string but probably that was before fixing other errors. Also I thought that JSON.stringify could stringify anything :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @wOxxOm, the problem here was that I was trying to JSONify a complex object. Adding .toString works. My bad!