# Chrome extension : sendResponse returning empty object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know there are a lot of similar questions : [Chrome extension messaging: sendResponse returning empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993250/chrome-extension-messaging-sendresponse-returning-empty-object), etc., but I read and tried all of them before asking my question.
My problem is a bit different, so I think that's why their solutions don't work for me.

I want to detect Ctrl+C from the user, so when he clicks on extension icon, the content of the clipboard is displayed inside the popup.

Here's what I've done :
a part of manifest.json :

```
    "permissions": [
          "activeTab", "tabs", "<all_urls>", "clipboardRead"
        ],
        "content_scripts": [    
        {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["oncopy.js"]
        }
        ],
         "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
        }
```

oncopy.js (content script)

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870369/google-chrome-extensions-how-to-detect-copy-action-ctrl-c-and-edit-copy

    function onCopy(e) {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({event: "copy"});
    }
    document.addEventListener('copy',onCopy,true);
```

background.js (background script) :

```
    var clipboardContents;

    // This part of the script receive the 'copy' event.
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.event == "copy") {      
            // #### GET CLIPBOARD CONTENT #################################################
            bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();        // get the background page
            bg.document.body.innerHTML= "";                   // clear the background page

            // add a DIV, contentEditable=true, to accept the paste action
            var helperdiv = bg.document.createElement("div");
            document.body.appendChild(helperdiv);
            helperdiv.contentEditable = true;

            // focus the helper div's content
            helperdiv.innerHTML=""; // clear the buffer
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(helperdiv);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
            helperdiv.focus();

            // trigger the paste action
            bg.document.execCommand("Paste");

            clipboardContents = helperdiv.innerText;
            // ############################################################################
        }
        sendResponse({});
      });

    function send_response(callback){
        callback(clipboardContents);
    }

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
      // When we get a message from the popup
      send_response(function(clipboardContents) {
            sendResponse(clipboardContents.toString());
        });
        return true;

// I also tried sendResponse() only, wih and without the return true;
// I also tried sendResponse(clipboardContents) only and sendResponse({data: clipboardContents});
});
```

popup.js :

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('popup_opened',function(response){
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = response;
    // I tried response.data
    });
```

I always get :
response = an empy object
response.toString() = "[Object : object]"
response.data = undefined

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I hope you can help, and that the answer has not be explained elsewhere yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual cause of the problem is that extension.onMessage is a deprecated alias for runtime.onMessage so you have two listeners for the same event but only the first registered listener's sendResponse is transferred to the caller and that is `{}`.

That said, the entire workflow can be extremely simplified: there's no need for the background script or the content script so you can remove "background" and "content_scripts" from manifest.json. No need for messaging either.

You need a browser_action popup and simply read the clipboard in the popup script.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "clipboardRead"
  ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <p id=text contenteditable=true></p>
  <script src=popup.js></script>
</body>
```

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById('text').focus();
document.execCommand('paste');
```

This is the entire content of the extension.